# E486: Pattern not found

Tags: vim

I need to repoint a mount from `/IsilonAsperaVOD/data` to `/Isilon/asperavod/data`. Using vim I do:

```
:s/IsilonAsperaVOD/Isilon\\/asperavod/g
```

which returns the error. I can type out the path or copy/past with same effect...? how do I do this

Comment: I also tried :%s/IsilonAsperaVOD/IsilonDenver\\/asperavod/g

Comment: i know the string is right cause i can use "park cursor then #" method and it finds all occurrences of IsilonAsperaVOD...

Comment: What is your input? Because I guess you have more lines and any of them don't match your regex.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `:global` (as in your own answer), prefixing a `:%` range for the entire file will suffice (without that, the `:s` only applies to the current line).

The problem with your original attempt is that you've escaped twice; there needs to be a single backslash in front of the `/`:

```
:%s/IsilonAsperaVOD/Isilon\/asperavod/g
```

But, it's better to avoid the escaping altogether by using a different separator character:

```
:%s#IsilonAsperaVOD#Isilon/asperavod#g
```

Comment: Yes, after another try this :%s#save#delete#g worked

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```
:g/IsilonAsperaVOD/s//IsilonDenver\/asperavod/g
```

so, single escape for directory slash, and g (global) and then :s,  instead of :s (replace) even with %